# Azure MySql - Adding AD User To MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, azure

I am trying to add an Azure AD user to my Azure MySQL DB, so that he can authenticate using a token (instead of needing username / password). I am set as the Azure AD administrator of this DB.

I am signing in to MySql Workbench using my Azure AD user and a token generated in Azure CLI. Then, I am running the following command:

```
CREATE AADUSER 'useriwanttoadd@microsoft.com'
```

(following directions outlined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/how-to-configure-sign-in-azure-ad-authentication#creating-azure-ad-users-in-azure-database-for-mysql).
I am getting the following cryptic error which I cannot seem to find any useful information about:

```
Error Code: 9127. User error occurred while accessing Azure AD endpoint, please check if the managed identity assigned to server has sufficient privileges
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and finally got it working. Read these two articles and follow the instructions:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/flexible-server/how-to-azure-ad
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/flexible-server/concepts-azure-ad-authentication

The keys are to make sure that MySQL Flexible Server is setup to use a user-managed identity with the proper permissions in Azure AD (that was the part where I initially missed an item).

Note that you need an Azure Global Admin or Privileged Role Admin to grant those AAD permissions to the managed identity.

Comment: somehow i am unable to add those permissions mentioned in the documentation . we need to achieve it via power shell only ?